# using 3G instead connected Wi-Fi on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, wireless, 3g, wifi

all,
my iPhone application must be connected to the local network without Internet access via Wi-Fi and in the same time connected to Internet via 3G. It is possible to do programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. iOS will use the fasted internet connect (by type) to connect to.
Maybe you could use VPN?

Comment: No, VPN over 3G. There is just no way the get the iphone to use both 3G and Wifi

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not suit me. I have zigBee network and wi-fi router with my controll application. So, iPhone connection with this router available only via Wireless.

Comment: Well then you will have to rethink your strategy. There is no way to make it work like you want to.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I think, I try to use access point mode on iPhone

Comment: @rckoenes supposed I'm doing TCP. So iOS will close my 3G TCP socket and recreate a new one for Wifi ?

Comment: No you can not, iOS will determine which connection is user. You as an developer have no control over it.